# How is Growing Neural Gas used for clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I know how the algorithm works, but I'm not sure how it determines the clusters. Based on images I guess that it sees all the neurons that are connected by edges as one cluster. So that you might have two clusters of two groups of neurons each all connected. But is that really it?

I also wonder.. is GNG really a neural network? It doesn't have a propagation function or an activation function or weighted edges.. isn't it just a graph? I guess that depends on personal opinion a bit but I would like to hear them.

**UPDATE:**

This thesis www.booru.net/download/MasterThesisProj.pdf deals with GNG-clustering and on page 11 you can see an example of what looks like clusters of connected neurons. But then I'm also confused by the number of iterations. Let's say I have 500 data points to cluster. Once I put them all in, do I remove them and add them again to adapt die existing network? And how often do I do that?

I mean.. I have to re-add them at some point.. when adding a new neuron r, between two old neurons u and v then some data points formerly belonging to u should now belong to r because it's closer. But the algorithm does not contain changing the assignment of these data points. And even if I remove them after one iteration and add them all again, then the false assignment of the points for the rest of that first iteration changes the processing of the network doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

NG and GNG are a form of self-organizing maps (SOM), which are also referred to as "Kohonen neural networks".

These are based on older, much wider view of neutal networks when they were still inspired by nature rather than being driven by GPU capabilites of matrix operations. Back then, when you did not yet have massive-SIMD architectures yet, there was nothing bad about having neurons self-organize rather than being preorganized in strict layers.

I would not call them clustering although that term is commonly (ab-) used in related work. Because I don't see any strong propery of these "clusters".

SOMs are literally *maps* as in geography. A SOM is a set of nodes ("neurons") usually arranged in a 2d rectangular or hexagonal grid. (=the map). The positions in the input space are then optimized iteratively to fit the data. Because they influence their neighbors, they cannot move freely. Think of wrapping a net around a tree; the knots of the net are your neurons. NG and GNG appear to be pretty mich the same thing, but with a more flexible structure of nodes. But actually a nice property of SOMs is the 2d map that you can get.

The only approach I remember for clustering was to project the input data to the discrete 2d space of the SOM grid, then run k-means on this projection. It will probably work okayish (as in: it will perform similar to k-means), but I'm not convinced that it's theoretically well supported.

Comment: Well Fritzke himself said "Possible applications of our model are clustering [...]" and there are several papers on it. But they all only explain the algorithm and not how to interpret it's result. 

http://www.booru.net/download/MasterThesisProj.pdf also deals with that and on page 11 you can see an example of what looks like clusters of connected neurons. But then I'm also confused by the number of iterations. Let's say I have 500 data points to cluster. Once I put them all in, do I remove them and add them again to adapt die existing network?

Comment: To elaborate further on the "wider view of neural networks": GNG and SOMs are based specifically on Hebbian theory e.g. "cells that fire together wire together". While ANN's have at times narrowed the view of a neuron, you can see a relatively recent biological discussion on Hebb's rule on one of the neighboring StackExchange sites [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16863/hebbian-theory-fire-together-clarification).